# how to read file line by line in python

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to read below text file in python, I'm struggling to get as key value in output but its not working as expected:

test.txt

```
productId1 ProdName1,ProdPrice1,ProdDescription1,ProdDate1
productId2 ProdName2,ProdPrice2,ProdDescription2,ProdDate2
productId3 ProdName3,ProdPrice3,ProdDescription3,ProdDate3
productId4 ProdName4,ProdPrice4,ProdDescription4,ProdDate4
```

myPython.py

```
import sys
with open('test.txt') as f
  lines = list(line.split(' ',1) for line in f)
  for k,v in lines.items();
     print("Key : {0}, Value: {1}".format(k,v))
```

I'm trying to parse the text file and trying to print key and value separately. Looks like I'm doing something wrong here. Need some help to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect? What happens?

Comment: You have a syntax error at line 2 here

Comment: Why do you expect your `lines` list to have an `items` method??? `list` objects don't have "keys" and "values", that's for mappings, i.e. `dict` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're needlessly storing a list.

Loop, split and print

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.rstrip().split(' ',1) 
        print("Key : {0}, Value: {1}".format(k,v))
```

Comment: @alfasin Same thing

Comment: Why I'm getting blank line after each key and value - which is breaking my other logic

Comment: @cricket_007 same thing with the OP's example true, but won't work on samples that have more than one space and I like explicit better than implicit. Please excuse my pettiness...

Comment: @rubydeveloper Each line ends in a `\n`, a newline. Without the `rstrip()` , the newline is preserved. I assume that is causing an empty line somehere.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, with a list comprehension:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.split(' ',1) for line in f]
    for k, v in lines:
        print("Key: {0}, Value: {1}".format(k, v))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dict right of the bat with a dict comp and than iterate the list to print as you wanted.  What you had done was create a list, which does not have an `items()` method.

```
with open('notepad.txt') as f:
    d = {line.split(' ')[0]:line.split(' ')[1] for line in f}
    for k,v in d.items():
        print("Key : {0}, Value: {1}".format(k,v))
```

Comment: Why call `line.split()` **twice**?

Comment: i don't know how else to do it, since i need to split the key and the value.  how do you recommend doing otherwise?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Don't do something silly just to cram something in a comprehension.

Comment: Split once on the line before

Comment: yes it makes sense not to do that since  `split()` clearly costs more than assignment

Comment: @0TTT0 most definitely. It's just super redundant. In this *particular* case, you could do something like `dict(line.split(' ', 1) for line in f)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, but im sorry i dont know what the second argument in split does and couldn't figure it out from the docs, if you could enlighten me?

Comment: It's the maximum number of times you split, so it will return a `list` with a maximum of 2 items. consider: `'a b c d'.split(' ', 1)`

Comment: But more generally, the point I wanted to make was that there's nothing wrong with a for-loop. comprehension constructs give you marginal improvements in speed, their main advantage is clarity/elegance. So if you find yourself violating the DRY principle, it's a big signal that you should just use a for-loop :)

Answer (score 0):

`lines` is a list of lists, so the good way to finish the job is:

```
import sys
with open('test.txt') as f:
  lines = list(line.split(' ',1) for line in f)
for k,v in lines:
   print("Key : {0}, Value: {1}".format(k,v))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am reading too much into your description but I see one key, a space and a comma limited name of other fields.  If I interpret that as their being data for those items that is comma limited then I would conclude you want a dictionary of dictionaries.  That would lead to code like:

```
data_keys = 'ProdName', 'ProdPrice', 'ProdDescription', 'ProdDate'
with open('test.txt') as f:
  for line in f:
    id, values = l.strip().split()  # automatically on white space
    keyed_values = zip(data_keys, values.split(','))
    print(dict([('key', id)] + keyed_values))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the f.readlines() function that returns a list of lines in the file f. I changed the code to include f.lines in line 3.

```
import sys
with open('test.txt') as f:
  lines = list(line.split(' ',1) for line in f.readlines())
  for k,v in lines.items();
     print("Key : {0}, Value: {1}".format(k,v))
```

Comment: there is no `.lines` method, and anyway, you can iterate over the file-handler directly.